# passing PHP variable to sql query in oci_parse

Tags: php, sql, oracle-call-interface

I am passing a PHP varibale into a oracle sql query. but its not taking it properly giving me ORA errors like - invalid character. I tried escaping the varibale as \'$sid\', this makes error go, but the query doesnt return anything.
Is there a way to pass PHP variable to oracle query

```
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
   $sid = $_POST['action'];
   $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT emp from table emp='$sid'');
   oci_execute($stid);
}
```

I have removed to the database connection part for brevity.

Comment: First thing: fix your quotation marks. Change outer ones to double quotes: `"SELECT emp from table emp='$sid'"`

Comment: I tried that too. But still getting error as : oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character in /opt/lampp/htdocs/process.php on line 28

Comment: Try adding semicolon in the end of your query. `"SELECT emp from table emp='$sid';"`

Comment: This doesn't work too. If I replace the variable with a static value, it works. for e.g. $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT emp from table emp=\'sam\'');

Comment: Then I guess, you should bind your `php` variable to Oracle placeholder. See Examples section here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'SELECT emp from table emp=\'$sid\''` is a string that you pass exactly as it is to Oracle, this is why it doesn't work.

You need to use [`oci_bind_by_name`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) to bind a placeholder to a PHP variable.

Example:

```
$variable = 42;
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT col_name FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name > :num;');
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":num", $variable);
oci_execute($stid);
```