# bucle for insert php in oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, loops

I want to insert multiple records in oracle table. My code works for one record but when I use a $i counter, it doesn't work. The problem is on my sintaxis using $i

```
    for ($i = 1; $i < $num; $i++){
        $query="INSERT INTO MYTABLE (CODE, NAME) VALUES ('$_SESSION[CODE]', '$_SESSION[NAME.$i]')";
        $stid2 = oci_parse($conn, $query);
        $r=oci_execute($stid2);
}
```

thanks for your time!!

Hi all!
Solved assign the var outside the query.

```
    for ($i = 1; $i < $num; $i++){
        $NAME=$_SESSION[NAME.$i];
        $query="INSERT INTO MYTABLE (CODE, NAME) VALUES ('$_SESSION[CODE]', '$NAME')";
        $stid2 = oci_parse($conn, $query);
        $r=oci_execute($stid2);
}
```

Comment: echo your $query, and see for yourself if that makes sense. It is valid SQL?

Comment: Always parameterise your queries. See [passing PHP variable to sql query in oci\_parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292582/passing-php-variable-to-sql-query-in-oci-parse)

Comment: And when you use bind variables shown in the link above, you can do the `oci_parse()` before the loop starts; you don't need to call it in each iteration.